# Should URLs with Parameters be included in your sitemap

Tags: seo

We have shop pages on our website with pagination and faceted navigation

For example the main URL for one of our category pages is shop/return-address-labels

We then have a URL parameter for pagination (pg=2) which will append to the end of the URL e.g `shop/return-address-labels?pg=2`

We also have an "industry" filter which will append at the end of the URL e.g `shop/return-address-labels?industry%20i_26j%20profession=sports%20i_26j%20fitness`

My question is, do all of these URLs get submitted in the sitemap.xml file or just the main URL without the parameters?

Thanks for any insight into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the urls in which you want indexing. I am not sure you would want the industry filter urls listed - They might have canonical tags on ?

Comment: Thanks for this, the site map would be cleaner without these industry filter URLs as like you said they do have canonical tags on them

Answer (score 0):

shop/return-address-labels?pg=2 typically considered as dynamic pages which can be included in site map but good practice in terms of SEO is: Do they have unique content,Title, Description?

Comment: They do have unique titles and descriptions but their isn't any unique content on these. I am trying to clean up the sitemap so I will be removing any URLs that are 301 redirected and any URLs that have canonical tags on them.